# Cakephp link with params only

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to create a custom url like http://example.com/type_of_institution/institutin_name

I added the following lines in my /routes.php

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:type/:name',
    ['controller' => 'Institutions', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['type' => '[a-z_]+', 'name' => '[a-z_]+', 'pass' => ['type','name']]
);

//in my controller
public function view($type,$name){
   this->autoRender = false;
}
```

and I've tried with http://example.com/private_institution/test_institution, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class PrivateInstitution could not be found.
```

After I've change to

```
$routes->connect(
        'institutions/:type/:name',
        ['controller' => 'Institutions', 'action' => 'view'],
        ['type' => '[a-z_]+', 'name' => '[a-z_]+', 'pass' => ['type','name']]
    );
```

And worked with http://example.com/institutions/private_institution/test_institution

It is a way in Cakephp 3 to make an url only with params?(first example)

Comment: Do you have any other routes before that?

Comment: yes. and i have a fallback too like $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute'). Do It needs to be the first one?

Comment: please add all routes in question

Comment: 1) $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']); 2) $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']); 3)  $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    
    $routes->connect('/jobs/view/:payload/:job_title',
        ['controller' => 'Jobs','action' => 'view'],
        ['pass' =>['payload', 'job_title']]);